# CGI scripts on Apache2 gives 403 forbidden when the CGI are in a linked folder

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2, cgi

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 as a virtual machine. I have Apache2 2.4.18 installed.

I have a folder with cgi scripts that I want to use. To do that I placed a symlink to that folder in /usr/lib/cgi-bin.

When I call the script from firefox `localhost/cgi-bin/linkName/script.cgi` I get 403 forbidden error.

When I copy the script.cgi to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` and call it with `localhost/cgi-bin/script.cgi`, it runs but gives a software error since it lacks the surrounding files and folders.

I have `chmod 777` both the link and the folder it links to but I still get the error.

What else can I do other than coping all the files and folders into `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the symbolic link points to a directory, which is located outside of directories listed in your `"virtualhost".conf` files. So you need to write down necessary directives in your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (or `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf` or `/etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf`) file to access `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`. Something like:

```
Alias /cgi-bin/linkName /usr/lib/cgi-bin

<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        Options +ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        # etc..   
</Directory>
```

And maybe (but I'm not sure that it's necessary): `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/lib/cgi-bin`.

If you make `Alias /cgi-bin/linkName /usr/lib/cgi-bin` you do not need to make a symbolic link.

Comment: I have added what you suggested (without the etc...) to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf. Now I see the content of the script but not what it should display

Comment: @GadiArmony, I have edit my post. `Require all granted` was dropped. Also you need to `systemctl restart apache2.service`.

Comment: So is it works?

Comment: I have all 4 lines and it still show the text of the script

Comment: @GadiArmony, please remove `None` from `Options` directive.

Comment: It still looks the same

Comment: Ok, I have found the true way. My answer is a half of it. You need to read this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html Try to ad `Options +ExecCGI`.

Comment: Thank you, That almost did it. The cgi scripts might be written in a way that is not compatible with the new apache2. I ended up copying the whole folder into `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`